# Print text with delay in python by using signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals

How can I print text with delay of 1 second with using signal.
I don't want using sleep().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` class from `threading` module. It isn't using `sleep`.

```py
from threading import Timer

def examlpe_func():
    print("Nothing here")

t = Timer(1, examlpe_func)
t.start()
```